# What happens to requests to a service that is stopped with SIGSTOP

Tags: linux, networking, signals, socket

If you send a SIGSTOP to a web server, does the kernel just tell the network stack to block/sleep all connections to that server's socket(s) until it is continued?  It seems that the server timeout values don't matter; it will wait indefinitely, but how?

Will requests sit in the socket buffer indefinitely?  What if the web server gets tons of requests?  What happens when the socket buffer fills up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the point of view of any part of the system that isn't concerned with the process's state and stats, a process that is stopped (i.e. won't be scheduled until it receives a SIGCONT) is indistinguishable from a process that's running, but isn't responding to a particular query. For example, the network stack operates in the same way whether the process is stopped, or is doing work (using CPU time) but not making any system call, or is blocked in some system call that isn't unblocked by the network-originating event (e.g. waiting to read from a pipe), etc.

While the process is stopped, there's no such thing as a timeout in the process. There are usually no timeouts in the network stack either: the packet has been received by the machine, even if it hasn't gotten to the machine. As far as e.g. TCP transmission is concerned, the packet has been received and it's up to the application to respond.

If the socket's buffer fills up, the network stack will start dropping packets.

There's no reason why the behavior of the network stack would depend on the process's state. The process could come out of the stopped state at any time. There could be multiple processes listening on a socket, so any decision based on the process state would have to take all of them into account.

Comment: You can have more than one listening process on a given socket?  How do the processes know which one should read a given packet from the rx socket buffer in that case?  Or is it that the processes don't know, and you would only do this for load balancing several server processes, and it doesnt matter which process consumes a given packet from the socket?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal A very common case is that there's one process whose job it is to handle the communication, and it sometimes forks but the children never do anything with the socket. When multiple processes do have a socket open and are ready to react on it, it's typically for load balancing where it doesn't matter which process consumes the packet.